# Two elements affect one jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $("a.tip, div.thumbh").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({width:"162px", height:"162px", left:"-20px", top:"-20px"},100)
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({width:"122px", height:"122px", left:"0px", top:"0px"},100);
    });
```

I would like to animate only **a.tip** img child. How can i do that ?

Comment: Please provide the relevant html and describe what is currently happening and what you would like to happen.  The answers below are all making assumptions about the final result you are expecting.

Comment: Do you want the animation triggered on mouse enter for both elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could check `this`

`if($(this).is('a.tip'))`... do your stuff

Answer (score 0):

[Check](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) if the current element has the `tip` class using -

```
if ($(this).hasClass('tip')) {
    // do your animation
}
```

so that you can be sure that the current element is `a.tip`, and then animate its child images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a.tip, div.thumbh").mouseenter(function() {
    $("a.tip img").stop().animate({width:"162px", height:"162px", left:"-20px", top:"-20px"},100)
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("a.tip img").stop().animate({width:"122px", height:"122px", left:"0px", top:"0px"},100);
});
```

Comment: @dc5: Thnx. I am on my mobile and stackoverflow doesn't show a link for indentation while using it in mobile.